# Debian 11 (Bullseye): man stopped working after upgrade?

Tags: debian, man, groff

After a recent upgrade, man has stopped working, and I can't figure out why. This is my system:

```
# cat /etc/*release*
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

And this is what I see when I run man - ie an empty man-page:

```
# man ksh
 Manual page ksh(1) byte 0/0 (END) (press h for help or q to quit)
```

and after pressing `q`:

```
man: command exited with status 1: (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim) | (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE) | (cd /usr/share/man && preconv -e UTF-8) | (cd /usr/share/man && tbl) | (cd /usr/share/man && nroff -mandoc -rLL=156n -rLT=156n -Tutf8)
```

I haven't really found anything with `strace`, except a bit of output to stderr:

```
# grep 'write(2' man.trc
10614 write(2, "troff: can't find 'DESC' file\n", 30) = 30
10614 write(2, "troff: fatal error: sorry, I can"..., 44) = 44
10599 write(2, "man: ", 5)              = 5
10599 write(2, "command exited with status 1: (c"..., 299) = 299
10599 write(2, "\n", 1)                 = 1
#
# grep DESC man.trc
10613 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/groff/site-font/devutf8/DESC", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10613 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/groff/1.22.4/font/devutf8/DESC", O_RDONLY) = 3
10614 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/groff/site-font/devutf8/DESC", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10614 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/groff/1.22.4/font/devutf8/DESC", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
10614 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/font/devutf8/DESC", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10614 write(2, "troff: can't find 'DESC' file\n", 30) = 30
```

I changed the permissions on `/usr/share/groff/1.22.4/font/devutf8/DESC` to make is world readable, but it makes no difference.

Any ideas?

***Edit in response to comments:***

The error message shows the pipeline that appears to fail:

```
# man zip
man: command exited with status 1: (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim) | 
(cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE) | 
(cd /usr/share/man && preconv -e UTF-8) | (cd /usr/share/man && tbl) | 
(cd /usr/share/man && nroff -mandoc -rLL=156n -rLT=156n -Tutf8)
```

I tried to run it manually:

```
# gunzip -c /usr/share/man/man1/zip.1.gz | /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim | /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE | preconv -e UTF-8 | tbl | nroff -mandoc -rLL=156n -rLT=156n -Tutf8
```

And it produces the correct output; so whatever is going wrong must be before that part. Somewhere it must, presumably, unzip the manpage and feed it into the pipeline, but I can't spot it.

***Edit 2:***

I've looked into it some more - the funny thing is here:

```
# grep DESC man.trc
666097 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/groff/site-font/devutf8/DESC", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
666097 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/groff/1.22.4/font/devutf8/DESC", O_RDONLY) = 3
666098 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/groff/site-font/devutf8/DESC", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
666098 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/groff/1.22.4/font/devutf8/DESC", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
666098 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/font/devutf8/DESC", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
666098 write(2, "troff: can't find 'DESC' file\n", 30) = 30
```

So, pid 666097 finds `/usr/share/groff/1.22.4/font/devutf8/DESC` and opens it successfully. Then pid 666098 finds it, but get permissions denied.

How is that possible?

Comment: Does it help if you reinstall `groff-base`? `sudo apt reinstall groff-base`

Comment: @StephenKitt No, unfortunately not, but thanks for trying :-)

Comment: What does mandb -t say? Could you run mandb -c and see if there are any changes?

Comment: I've tried both now - mandb -t only lists a couple of warnings for specific man-pages, and mandb -c finished successfully. But still the same issue. Somehow the man pages seem to be formatted to an empty output stream.

Comment: @Alex I've updated the original question

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `groff` cannot find `/usr/share/groff/site-font/devutf8/DESC`. As I understood, that should be part of `groff-base`, so the comment that instructed you to `sudo apt reinstall groff-base` seems valid.

If the directory `/usr/share/groff/site-font/devutf8` does not exist, it may be that

```
ln -s /usr/share/groff/current/font/devutf8 /usr/share/groff/site-font/devutf8
```

will help `man` to find the `DESC` file.

If the directory does exist, but does not contain a `DESC`, then copying `DESC` from `/usr/share/groff/current/font/devutf8` might help.

If `DESC` is there, verify that it is readable (`644`).